# I am compiling my Vuejs app using electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I was successfully compiled but whenever I run the application it says `SyntaxError` cannot use `import` out side module

[image]

which is I understand inside my background.js

```
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
```

So I tried to change it to something `const { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');` but still it keeps showing the same error message.

How do I resolve this or I am doing it correctly?

heres my full `scr/background.js`

```
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
    { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 850,
        minWidth: 1000,
        minHeight: 850,
        // autoHideMenuBar: true,
        // frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
            contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    })

    if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
        // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
        await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
        // Open Dev console
        // if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
    } else {
        createProtocol('app')
        // Load the index.html when not in development
        win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
    }
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async () => {
    if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
        // Install Vue Devtools
        try {
            await installExtension(VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS)
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
        }
    }
    createWindow()
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
    if (process.platform === 'win32') {
        process.on('message', (data) => {
            if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
                app.quit()
            }
        })
    } else {
        process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
            app.quit()
        })
    }
}
```

And my package.json

```
{
    ....

    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "build-installer": "electron-builder",
        "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
        "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
        "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
        "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
    },
    "main": "src/background.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "@electron/remote": "^2.0.9",
        "@vueuse/core": "^10.1.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10",
        "core-js": "^3.8.3",
        "postcss": "^8",
        "tailwindcss": "^3",
        "vue": "^3.2.13"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "electron": "^11.0.0",
        "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.1.1",
        "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~3.0.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
            "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
        },
        "rules": {}
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not dead",
        "not ie 11"
    ],
    "build": {
        "appId": "---",
        "win": {
            "target": [
                "nsis"
            ],
            "icon": "src/assets/logo.ico",
            "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
        },
        "nsis": {
            "installerIcon": "src/assets/logo.ico",
            "uninstallerIcon": "src/assets/logo.ico",
            "uninstallDisplayName": "---",
            "license": "license.md",
            "oneClick": false,
            "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `require`? instead of `import`?

Comment: yes @FemiBlack i tried something like this `const { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');` and so on for other `import`

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: No, @FemiBlack, I am using Vue JS, Electron and Tailwind only